# kinect cad model for urfd rviz

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, urdf, cad

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Does anybody know if there is a kinect CAD model of the camera anywhere.

I wanted to show the model in rviz, but for that I needed an .stl or .dae file with a model of the kinect.

Thanks

Miguel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49759/kinect-cad-model-for-urfd-rviz/) by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 254 on 2012-12-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-06**:
If you got a correct answer, please mark it as correct. Press the little check mark below the downvote button.

**Comment by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on 2012-12-07**:
Hello Lorenz. I have marked it as correct. Sorry about that :)

**Comment by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on 2012-12-07**:
Hello Lorenz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

there is one in turtlebot_description package, under meshes directory. it is kinect.dae

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2012-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miguel Riem de Oliveira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1178/miguel-riem-de-oliveira/) on 2012-12-07**:
Thanks. Found it